# Charts for Windows 8 Metro Application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

Can any one suggest me some API to create dynamic charts for my Windows 8 Metro Application created using C# and XAML?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look to [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/): it contains controls that support pie charts, bar charts, scatter charts, etc. (ported from Silverlight Toolkit's Chart).

Answer (score 2):

[Google Chart Image Api](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) & [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/) are nice API's for creating charts.

> The Google Chart API lets you **dynamically generate charts with a URL string**. You can embed these charts on your web page, or **download the image for local or offline use.**

[image: line]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/cbuu3mlc.wbh.png))</sub>

[image: bar]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/vej5zo0c.xk3.png))</sub>

This works with `C#`... I made a weather application back in `2007` that made use of the API.

[image: capp]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/xdrhydlu.byi.png))</sub>

There were some visual bugs here and there, But the API has been updated since then.

Comment: Does it work for Metro apps as the OP asked?

Comment: Yeah it should it creates an image based on a url you send to the API, then its just a matter of streaming the image back to the application (isn't much else to it).

Answer (score 1):

We use Microsoft Chart.

[Download: Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET Framework Documentation - Microsoft Download Center - Download Details](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=11001)

It works on .NET 4 as well as 3.5 - I haven't tried it on 4.5 yet, but I should think it works.

It probably won't work for a Metro App though, if that's what you wanted it for (you didn't specify if it was for Windows RT in your question)

Comment: thanks fr the reply, but i want it for metro app.....